# Kafka connect Flatten SMT

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using the [mongo DB sink connector](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/sink-connector/) and trying to use the [Flatten SMT](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/flatten.html).
My Kafka message looks like this:

```
{
    "entity": {
        "_id": "62ade225a28f13001127297a",
        "status": "Critical",
        "severity": "Critical",
        "is_active": true,
        "source_system": "api.test",
        "tags": [
            {
                "type": "host",
                "value": "host123"
            },
            {
                "type": "check",
                "value": "check123"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My main goal is to flatten the entity object in order to keep only a few fields, for example:

```
{
    "_id": "62ade225a28f13001127297a",
    "status": "Critical",
    "severity": "Critical",
    "is_active": true
}
```

My configurations are:

```
{
    "name": "kafka-to-mongo",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics.regex": "test_topic",
        "connection.uri": "mongodb://mongodb4:27017/auto-resolve",
        "database": "auto-resolve",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": false,
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "collection": "autoresolve_schedules",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "document.id.strategy": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.PartialValueStrategy",
        "document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.list": "entity._id",
        "document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.type": "AllowList",
        "writemodel.strategy": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.ReplaceOneBusinessKeyStrategy",
        "transforms": "HoistField,ReplaceField,flatten",
        "transforms.HoistField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.HoistField$Key",
        "transforms.HoistField.field": "key",
        "transforms.ReplaceField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
        "transforms.ReplaceField.whitelist": "entity",
        "transforms.flatten.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten$Value",
        "transforms.flatten.delimiter": "."
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:514)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:469)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:325)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:228)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:196)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:184)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Flatten transformation does not support class java.util.ArrayList for record without schemas (for field entity.tags).
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten.applySchemaless(Flatten.java:134)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten.applySchemaless(Flatten.java:131)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten.applySchemaless(Flatten.java:99)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten.apply(Flatten.java:75)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.lambda$apply$0(TransformationChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
    ... 14 more
```

What am I doing wrong? In addition, I wanted to investigate it a little bit and see why I get this error so I cloned the [Flatten class from the Kafka repo](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/Flatten.java), I added a test that takes my message (json string) and converts it with the Jackson object mapper. Then, use the apply method of the Flatten class. Superinsgly, I didn't get any exceptions and the transformer worked as expected (in the Junit test).

Comment: Do you have a schema for this topic?

Comment: No @Gibbs. Why?

Comment: As the error says - flatten not supported for record without schemas

Comment: I think you'll have to parse the record and "flatten" without tags element before consuming in the sink... Otherwise, you're going to need a transform that's the opposite of HoistField, then remove tags with the Replace whitelist... I'm not sure what your test code looked like, but sounds like you converted the whole record to a string rather than actually having a map / JsonObject with an array value